# What table/view do you query against to select all the table names in a schema in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What object do you query against to select all the table names in a schema in Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see all the tables you have access to

```
select table_name from all_tables where owner='<SCHEMA>';
```

To select all tables for the current logged in schema (eg, your tables)

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use:

```
select tabname from tabs
```

to get the name of tables present in schema.

Comment: tabs is deprecated in Oracle, and it's tabs.table_name